# Using Simple HTML Dom Parser to Get hyphenated Attribute

Tags: php

There is a similar question to this on StackOverflow. But, My question is a little different.

I have selected the image with the required class whose image I want. Earlier, I used

`element->src`

to get the value of src attribute, but now the site has replaced it with 'data-src'.

I do not have the full contents of a tag, hence I can not use preg_replace. I Have the reqired element, I just want to be able to do something like

`$element->data-src`

I am trying to do this using PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER, but no luck yet.

Comment: whould this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634599/using-xml-node-names-with-hyphens-in-php

Answer (score 15):

Try using

```
$element->{'data-src'}
```