# Access specific node (custom_field) simplexml

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, simplexml

This XML file, which can be accessed here @ http://afdclinics.com/persistentpresence/category/brentwood/lobby-1/feed/ - has a custom_fields node with 2 fields called custom-bgcolor, and custom-fontcolor. I have tried numerous ways to try, and access the data inside them with no luck.

I have been accessing other nodes with simplexml, but haven't been able to get the custom_fields working. Here is what I have so far.

```
$curl = curl_init();        
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'http://afdclinics.com/persistentpresence/category/brentwood/lobby-1/feed/');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
$result = curl_exec ($curl);   

if ($result === false) {
die('Error fetching data: ' . curl_error($curl));   
}
curl_close ($curl);    

//we can at this point echo the XML if you want
//echo $result;

//parse xml string into SimpleXML objects
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

if ($xml === false) {
die('Error parsing XML');   
}

//now we can loop through the xml structure
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
//print $item->title;       rss feed article title
//print $item->description; rss feed article description
//print $item->link;        rss feed article link
//print $item->pubDate;     rss feed article publish date
print $item->children('content', true); //rss feed article content


// here is where is would like to print the custom values
    print $item->custom_fields->custom-bgcolor;  // this line doesn't seem to work

//gets img url's and appends them to offline manifest file
$imgUrl = array();  
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->loadHTML($item->children('content', true));
$imgUrl = simplexml_import_dom($doc2);
$images = $imgUrl->xpath('//img');

foreach ($images as $img) {                     
    $imgUrl = $img['src'] . "\r\n"; 
    print $imgUrl;      //rss feed image url's
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using XML node names with hyphens in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634599/using-xml-node-names-with-hyphens-in-php)

Comment: Worked like a charm, just needed to use the syntax as suggested in the link above.                                                         $item->{'custom_fields'}->{'custom-bgcolor'}